# check bit version of running program

Tags: java

I have a data manipulation program that I run from within eclipse (no GUI).  I need to check the bit version of java so that I can compare it with the bit version of database connections and the like.

The following code prints out the memory address of the java runtime:

```
System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().toString());
```

How can I change that line of code so that it prints out the bit version of the running instance of java instead?

Other posts about this seemed to focus on other aspects like swing gui, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The `os.arch` property should give you the JVM architecture. See [this post](https://blogs.oracle.com/DieterDeramoudt/entry/beware_when_detecting_32_and) for details.

Comment: That looks like it gives the operating system bit version.  I want to be able to check the java bit version, particularly as it changes when I specify different jdk's in eclipse.  Can you help with that?

Comment: Please take a look at the link, especially the last sentence of the post.  Maybe it was thought to be the system architecture, but in fact it is the JVM architecture -- at least for Oracle.